# Python: Date field in dataframe incorrectly sorting in ascending order (certain dates out of place)

Tags: python, sorting, date, dataframe

I have a Date column that I converted from object to datetime using the code below:

```
df_MS_rep_2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MS_rep_2['Date'])
```

Then I tried to sort the Date column in ascending order but my output is incorrect.  Please see table below... highlighted yellow rows show the output error.

[image]

Below is the code I used to sort.  Any insight on what I did wrong is greatly appreciated!

```
df_MS_rep_3 = df_MS_rep_2.sort_values(['ID', 'Date'])
```

Comment: What happens if you sort by `Date` only?

Comment: hmmm... when I only sort by Date then it is ascending correctly .. what does this mean?

Comment: Not sure, but is probably means the sort is not doing multiple keys correctly.